# Other references for Manyu

Tags: gods

A part from RIGVEDA 10.83 and 10.84 , where is possible to find other references about Deva Manyu?

And where are its representation in Hinduism iconography?

Answer (score 3):

Although I'm not sure it's the same Manyu, you can find the background story to this deity in the [Gautama-mahatmya](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/gautami-mahatmya/d/doc216813.html) (the fourth part of the Brahma-purana):

> Devas spoke to the lord, “For our victory, give unto us a man who is extremely praiseworthy and who will take up command of our army in the battle. May we be happy by resorting to the strength of his arms.”
>
> Lord Maheśvara said to Devas “So be it.” A certain (deity) was created by the supreme lord by his own brilliance. **He was an extremely terrible fellow named Manyu. He was (to be) the leader of the army of Devas.** After obtaining him, Devas bowed to Śiva and returned to their abodes accompanied by Manyu. They then stood ready for battle once again.

Further on he reveals his true nature:

> Manyu was the lord himself born from him in separate forms. He shall be in the form of Rudra. Rudra became Manyu and Śiva. Everything, the mobile and immobile is pervaded by Manyu (Anger).

As for the iconography, you can derive it from various scriptures. For example, in the same book it is mentioned that he has his own "refulgence" and carries "all types of weapons":

> On seeing that representative of Śaṅkara, who was resplendent on account of his own refulgence and who was holding aloft all types of weapons, Devas bowed to him. Daityas and Danujas became afraid. Devas joined their palms in reverence.

The [Shatapatha Brahmana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/satapatha-brahmana-english/d/doc63364.html) also mentioned few iconographic features:

> 6. And as to why he performs the Śatarudriya offering. When Prajāpati had become disjointed, the deities departed from him. Only one god did not leave him, to wit, Manyu (wrath): extended he remained within. **He (Prajāpati) cried, and the tears of him that fell down settled on Manyu. He became the hundred-headed, thousand-eyed, hundred-quivered Rudra.** And the other drops that fell down, spread over these worlds in countless numbers, by thousands; and inasmuch as they originated from crying (rud), they were called Rudras (roarers). That hundred-headed, thousand-eyed, hundred-quivered Rudra, with his bow strung, and his arrow fitted to the string, was inspiring fear, being in quest of food. The gods were afraid of him.

Answer (score 1):

in srimad bhagavat purana https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/12/12/

> Lord Brahmā said: My dear boy Rudra, you have eleven other names: Manyu, Manu, Mahinasa, Mahān, Śiva, Ṛtadhvaja, Ugraretā, Bhava, Kāla, Vāmadeva and Dhṛtavrata.